# Make a custom notification smaller than default size in android

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, custom-notification

It's a while since I'm trying to make a small notification. After some researches i found that the default size is 64 dp, but is it possible to reduce this minimum size?
I found an app that makes this very small notification:
[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5kunskccjf0cniw/Screenshot_20171012-131214_01.jpg?dl=0]

Do you know how to do something like that?
I tried with custom notification but even if I set a different size in activity_main.xml it didn't change.

Comment: default size vary with each platform

Comment: Could you post your code?